# OPENAI GPT-4 response length limit

Tags: openai-api, gpt-4

I am writing prompt for generating blog using gpt-4, ant it always returns around 700 words long response.

Followings are prompts I tried.

`Write a 2000 words long blog about ...`

`Length: 2000 words`

`Response characters 8000 characters`

I have prompt saying  prompt at the end
`Write _THE_END_ at the end of the repsonse`

and let my python script check for the keyword _THEEND before sending
continue
prompt to again.

Please help me with the prompt that will actually generate 2000+ words response.

I expect output from gpt-4 to be a 2000+ words long.
but it's always around 700 words long

Comment: Why did you add Openair tag? Did you mean OpenAI?